# webapp on tomcat 7 only available via ssl (http not working, https working)

Tags: http, https, tomcat7, server.xml

i did a restart of my tomcat 7 web-server yesterday, because I deployed a second webapp. I have added a 'GlobalNamingResources' to server.xml but did not change anything else!

After the restart my ROOT App was not accessible anymore via http, only via https.

Here are my connectors from server.xml:

```
<Connector 
        port="8080" 
        protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
        connectionTimeout="20000" 
        redirectPort="443"

       compression="on"
       noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
       compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml, .... [some more]"
        />

<Connector 
       port="8443" 
       maxThreads="200"
       scheme="https" 
       secure="true" 
       SSLEnabled="true"
       keystoreFile="${catalina.base}/conf/.keystore" 
       keystorePass="***"
       clientAuth="false" 
       sslProtocol="TLS"

       compression="on"
       noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
       compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml, .... [some more]"
       />
```

could it be that redirectPort="443" should better be redirectPort="8443"? However, this was working before.

highly appreciate any ideas. Thank you!